# WordPress - tap into MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, instance

What variable is used for the database connection instance in WordPress?

PS: I would be wanting to use the variable from the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" )

Please refer this link
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class